# Disable \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} on \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, lengths

I use `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` and it is great. But I want to disable it just for the `\tableofcontents`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the more general idea here is that you have a length that is set in the preamble, but want it to be different for a specific part of your document.

For this, store the length before setting it using something like

```
\newlength{\storeparskip}
\setlength{\storeparskip}{\parskip}% Store \parskip
...
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}% Set \parskip
```

Then, where you need the adjusted `\parskip` to be restored, use

```
\begingroup%
\setlength{\parskip}{\storeparskip}% Restore \parskip within this scope
...%
\endgroup%
```

The scoping (via an explicit `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` pair, or using `{`...`}`) will restore the lengths to their pre-scope values.